# wine dependency problem

Tags: wine, software-installation

I have 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 on my system. with nvidia graphic card. i installed some packages off line by using dpkg and also some programs from source code. now i have problem installing wine on my system. i have tried these commands:

- `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

but it gives me this:

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.12-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i have also tried aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude install wine1.7
```

one of the solution it suggests is this :

```
     Remove the following packages:                                   
1)      empathy                                                        
2)      espeak                                                         
3)      ffmpeg                                                         
4)      gnome-media                                                    
5)      gstreamer0.10-plugins-good                                     
6)      indicator-sound                                                
7)      libasound2-plugins                                             
8)      libav-tools                                                    
9)      libavdevice53                                                  
10)     libcanberra-pulse                                              
11)     libespeak1                                                     
12)     libfarstream-0.1-0                                             
13)     libfluidsynth-dev                                              
14)     libfluidsynth1                                                 
15)     libjack-dev                                                    
16)     libjack0                                                       
17)     libportaudio2                                                  
18)     libpurple0                                                     
19)     libtelepathy-farstream2                                        
.
.
.                                     
      Install the following packages:                                  
40)     libcanberra-gstreamer [0.28-3ubuntu3 (precise)]                

      Keep the following packages at their current version:            
.
.
.                              
63)     wine1.7 [Not Installed]                                        
64)     wine1.7-amd64 [Not Installed]                                  
65)     wine1.7-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                              

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                     
.
.
.
84)     wine1.7-amd64 recommends libasound2-plugins                    
85)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libasound2-plugins:i386           
86)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libsane:i386                      
87)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libxcomposite1:i386               
88)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libxcursor1:i386                  
89)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libxi6:i386                       
90)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libxinerama1:i386                 
91)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libxrandr2:i386                   
92)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libxrender1:i386                  
93)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libxt6:i386                       
94)     wine1.7-i386:i386 recommends libxxf86vm1:i386
```

as it shows aptitude is going to delete many unrelated packages and not installing wine.
i don't know how resolve this dependecy problem. i could install wine on newly installed ubuntu but in my case i don't know what packages are causing this problem. i also tried other version of wine such as wine `wine1.6` `wine1.4` `wine1.3`. i also tried installing wine from source code but it only can run non gui applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think your base system needs to be upgraded, because the PPA wine is depending on something newer than what you have.  Have you turned on Backports and Proposed updates in Software Sources?  After doing so, you'll need to either:

```
apt-get safe-upgrade
```

OR

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

before attempting to install Wine.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error a couple weeks ago, when I tried to install wine.

I believe I fixed this by using the command

`sudo apt-get install wine1.7 --fix-missing`

the `--fix-missing` tag does exactly what it says it does: fix missing packages. If that doesn't work, try to use

`sudo apt-get install wine1.7 --fix-broken`

or

`sudo apt-get install wine1.7 -f`

I forgot which one it was, but one of those installed wine for me, with the same error you are getting.